# Delete/select sub string in R and create a new columns

Tags: r, string

I have a data which looks like this:

```
area_fips   area_title
01000       Alabama -- Statewide
02000       Alaska -- Statewide
12000       Florida -- Statewide
```

Now, I want to only select the first two characters for the column or the variable area_flips and create a new variable called state_code containing those two characters so that new data would like this:

```
area_fips   area_title             state_code
01000       Alabama -- Statewide   01
02000       Alaska -- Statewide    02
12000       Florida -- Statewide   12
```

My use of R especially when it comes to string manipulation unfortunately is not good. I kindly request your help on this. Thank you

Comment: Though answers are trickling in, what did you try? Generally the community likes to see some trials and tribulations rather than writing code for posters, it also helps us understand what you are looking for or where your challenges may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df$state_code <- substr(df$area_fips, 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `sub`

```
df1$state_code <- sub("^(.{2}).*", "\\1", df1$area_fips)
df1$state_code
#[1] "01" "02" "12"
```